# Rails doesn't seem to randomize primary key after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, random, primary-key

I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies, but I get the following errors when trying to create a (generic) joke (model):

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key   'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `jokes` (`content`, `created_at`, `id`, `rating`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('dsfgdsfgdfgd', '2013-02-27 16:33:12', 90650754896700, 0, '2013-02-27 16:33:12')):
  app/controllers/jokes_controller.rb:141:in `create'
  app/controllers/jokes_controller.rb:140:in `create'
```

And when I try to save another one:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `jokes` (`content`, `created_at`, `id`, `rating`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('dsfgdsfg', '2013-02-27 16:32:23', 29733688655250, 0, '2013-02-27 16:32:23')):
  app/controllers/jokes_controller.rb:141:in `create'
  app/controllers/jokes_controller.rb:140:in `create'
```

The error mentions that I have a duplicate entry (the primary key 2147483647). I am only able to create one joke ever. I never had this problem before deployment, the only notable thing I can think of which changed is the database type, from sqlite3 to mysql2.

Here's the important code bits from my joke model:

```
before_create :randomize_id
#...
validates :content, :presence   => true
validates :content, :uniqueness => true
#...
  private
def randomize_id
begin
  self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(100_000_000_000_000)
end while Joke.where(:id => self.id).exists?
end
```

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is too large. You can only put a 32 bit (signed) integer in that ID field. Not sure why you're trying to create your own primary key, but anyway, try this:

```
  self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(1000_000_000)
```

By the way (2^32)/2 -1 = 2147483647

Comment: No problem, though I do wonder why you're creating your own primary key? You could just let mysql do it's thing and create them for you. Anyway, glad to help

Comment: Ah, I wanted them to assigned id's in a specific way, the randomize was just a place holder =)